# I'm pulling the div content inside the form with load. However, I cannot post the input in the content

Tags: ajax, forms, load

```
        function xgonder(){
        var veriler = $('#gonder').serialize();
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "sendurl",
        data: veriler,
        success:function(e){
        $("#tamam").html(e);
        }
        })};
   
   
       
    
         <form id="gonder" action="javascript:void(0);"  method="POST">
            
            <input  class="form-control" id="kimlik" type="text" name="kimlik">
            
            <div id="icerial"></div>
        
        <button class="btn  btn-success float-right" onclick="xgonder();" type="submit">
        <i class="far fa-check-circle"></i> Bitir </button> 
        
        </form>
   
    <div id="tamam"></div>
    
    icerial div load

    icerial.html
    
        <input type="radio" id="algel" name="algel" value="1">
        <input type="radio" id="algel" name="algel" value="2">
```

this is my problem
When I load the page, when I post the form, the entry on the page is not sent.
where is the mistake

Thanks to the friends who gave important answers to me

Comment: HI, is there any error inside browser console ?

Comment: Hi, No error code

Comment: is your page refreshes when you click on submit button ? If yes use `onclick="xgonder(ev);"`  then add `function xgonder(ev){` lastly use `ev.preventDefault();` line inside your function.

Comment: I did it didn't work, does not post

Comment: where are you trying to post datas ? show `sendurl` page . Also , check your browser network tab -> XHR see if ajax call is initiated or not .

Comment: kimlik input send page no problem.

Comment: tamam div doesn't send what's inside

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved

tamam div ad form id="gonder2"

```
$('#gonder').append($('#tamam #gonder2').children());
var veriler = $('#gonder').serialize();
```

Thx.